# Calling a subclass method from SuperClass C

Tags: c++

I have a SuperClass "BoardMain" and 6 members that are subclasses to this main Function.

However, When I try to call the Specific function in one of the subclasses , I get the error

"Cannot allocate an object of abstract type  "

I have an access only to the "BoardMAin" superclass , which should call specific function in one of the subclasses .

Please Help

```
Class Someother
{
  Boardmain.functionA();
}


class BoardMain
{
functionA 
{
   B();
}

}

Class B1:public BoardMain() 
{
B(){
}
}
```

Comment: Please try to make a minimal code example (one super class and one sub class should be enough) that demonstrates the problem and post the code here.

Comment: Really ?? This is not the code you tried to compile I hope ... Methods with no return type, everything in private, no constructor, you try to call a method statically even if it is not static...

Comment: Please provide a small code snippet that reproduces the error, and add all error messages you receive. Try to find a solution yourself (and state what you have tried) before posting a question.

Comment: Still the code looks incomplete or wrong. Try to generate the error with minimal code as suggested post the complete minimal code.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain all the errors in the code :

```
Class Someother
{
    Boardmain.functionA(); // Error 1
}


class BoardMain
{
    functionA // Error 2
    {
       B();   // Error 3
    }

}

Class B1:public BoardMain() // Error 4
{
    B(){ // Error 5
    }
}
```

#### Error 1

You are calling a method directly inside a class, it is impossible in C++. Call it from a method.

After you are trying to call a method from another class statically, I mean not on an instance of an object. Here you have to choices :

- Declare this method statically in the `Boardmain` class with the keyword `static`
- Create an instance of `Boardmain` and call the method, example :

  ```
  class Someother
  {
  public:           // public accessibility
      Someother()   // Constructor of the class
      {
          Boardmain obj;     // Object creation
          obj.functionA();   // Calling the method
      }
  };
  ```

Last thing, at the point you are declaring the class `Someother`, the class `Boardmain` is still not known by the compiler... It will give you an error here...

#### Error 2

You are declaring a function without return-type and without argument, again this is not possible in C++. At least the `()` are needed for a constructor.

This example is correct :

```
class BoardMain
{
    void functionA() // Does not return anything and does not take argument
    {
    }
};
```

#### Error 3

You are calling a function named `B`, but.... WHAT IS IT ?? The method declared in `B1` ?

#### Error 4

When a class inherit from another, the correct declaration is :

```
class B1:public BoardMain  // no () a the end
```

#### Error 5

Again you are not declaring this method correctly. If you want it to be a constructor, it should have the same name as the class :

```
class B1 : public BoardMain
{
    B1(){    // Private constructor
    }
};
```

---

By the way, the `class` keyword is **ALWAYS** in lowercase in C++. And there is semicolon at the end of a `class` declaration.

---

You should buy a good book to learn C++, it seems you need it.

Here is a documentation about `class` : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Answer (score 0):

You should implement all pure virtual methods of all base classes for the derived classes you wish to instantiate.

Your error message indicates that this is not be the case at some point in your code (which you have not shown to us).